# Displaying a copy-pastable and well structured BibTeX key in my document

Tags: listings, pdf, copy-paste

**Context:** I want to insert the BibTeX entry of my document at the beginning thereof. I thus want this code snippet meet two criteria:

1. Be easily copy-paste-able (code seen = code copy-pasted)
2. Looks good (enable 'structuring' of the code snippet with both tabs and spaces).

> What? Using tabs *and* spaces for formatting code??! What a sacrilege!

Don't you say? Here is an example of the code snippet to make things more explicit:

```
@article{Turing1950,
⇥Title␣␣␣=␣{Computing machinery and intelligence},
⇥Author␣␣=␣{Turing, Alan~M.},
⇥Journal␣=␣{Mind},
⇥Year␣␣␣␣=␣{1950},
⇥Pages␣␣␣=␣{433--460},
⇥Volume␣␣=␣{59},
}
```

I here distinguish syntactical indentation done with <kbd>Tab</kbd> (and here represented with `⇥`), from indentation for outlook only (i.e. in order to make all `=` be aligned) done with  <kbd>Space</kbd>  and here represented with `␣`.

**Issue:** I use a simple `lstlisting` environment. The result looks great but it got unwanted line breaks when I copy-paste it [see MWE 1].

I also tried the solution proposed by Martin Monperrus on [his website](http://www.monperrus.net/martin/copy-pastable-listings-in-pdf-from-latex). Copy-paste works pretty well (no unwanted line-break, yet equal signs are not aligned), but the look does not. [see MWE 2].

I have also tested the various possibilities for `listings`' `column` setting  but none is fully satisfying (see below). `verbatim` environment doesn't work neither (for both look and copy-paste).

**Question:** How to display a copy-pastable and well structured BibTeX key in my document?

---

### MWE 1

- code:

  ```
  \documentclass{scrbook}
      \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      \usepackage{textcomp}
      \usepackage{listings}
          \lstset{%
              basicstyle=\ttfamily,
              tabsize=2,
              breaklines=true,
              breakindent=1em,
              upquote=true,
              columns=[c]fixed,
              literate={*}{{\char42}}1
                       {-}{{\char45}}1
          }
  \begin{document} 
  \begin{lstlisting}
  @article{Turing1950,
      Title   = {Computing machinery and intelligence},
      Author  = {Turing, Alan~M.},
      Journal = {Mind},
      Year    = {1950},
      Pages   = {433--460},
      Volume  = {59},
  }
  \end{lstlisting}
  \end{document}
  ```
- Display:
  [image]
- Copy-paste:

  ```
  @article { Turing1950 ,
  Title
  = { Computing machinery and intelligence } ,
  Author = { Turing , Alan ~ M .} ,
  Journal = { Mind } ,
  Year
  = {1950} ,
  Pages
  = {433 - - 460} ,
  Volume = {59} ,
  }
  ```

---

### MWE 2

- code:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp}
  \usepackage{listings}
  \lstset{ 
  %basicstyle=\ttfamily,% <----- make things even worse
  upquote=true,
  columns=fullflexible,
  literate={*}{{\char42}}1
           {-}{{\char45}}1
           {\ }{{\copyablespace}}1
  }

  \usepackage[space=true]{accsupp}
  % requires the latest version of package accsupp
  \newcommand{\copyablespace}{
      \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=00A0}
  \ %
      \EndAccSupp{}
  }

  \begin{document} 
  \begin{lstlisting}
  @article{Turing1950,
      Title   = {Computing machinery and intelligence},
      Author  = {Turing, Alan~M.},
      Journal = {Mind},
      Year    = {1950},
      Pages   = {433--460},
      Volume  = {59},
  }
  \end{lstlisting}
  \end{document}
  ```
- Display:
  [image]
- Copy-paste:

  ```
  @article{Turing1950,
  Title       =   {Computing   machinery   and   intelligence},
  Author     =   {Turing,   Alan~M.},
  Journal   =   {Mind},
  Year         =   {1950},
  Pages       =   {433--460},
  Volume     =   {59},
  }
  ```

---

**`columns=fixed`**  copy-paste = ✘ | display = ✔
**`columns=flexible`**  copy-paste = ✘ | display = ✘ (`year` only messes up in copy-paste)
**`columns=spaceflexible`**  copy-paste = ✘ | display = ✘ (`year` only messes up in copy-paste)
**`columns=fullflexible`**  copy-paste = ✘ | display = ✘

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the BibTeX of my document". (The usual meaning of "BibTeX" is that it's an executable program.) E.g., are you looking to create a document that typesets the contents of a bib file in some special verbatim mode, with distinctions made between tab characters ("soft spaces") and hard spaces?

Comment: @Mico : I just miss-typed "BibTeX *entry*", my bad. On the back of the title page of my thesis, I want to insert the copy-pastable BibTeX reference of the document.

Comment: @ebo -- to make the question a bit less confusing, please edit the title as well to say "entry" and not "key".  that said, i don't think i know any way of presenting this information in the visual format you want unless it's treated as verbatim.  and even then, i don't know that copy-paste will retain the spacing.